# How to remove ripple emulator using npm

Tags: npm, debian, ripple

Have problem with uninstaling ripple emulator at Debian Jessie.

Was instaled by command

```
sudo npm install -g ripple-emulator
```

But when I try to uninstall using command

```
sudo npm rm ripple-emulator
```

It gives warning

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/user/node_modules: "ripple-emulator"
```

I have change location to /usr/share/npm/node_modules/ but there no folder with ripple emulator

Answer (score 2):

If installed with the `-g` flag you need to pass that in when uninstalling as well. So the following should work:

`sudo npm rm -g ripple-emulator`